# Selecting a type of distribution for a problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

"Among 30 raffle tickets six are winners. Felicia buys 10 tickets. Find the
probability that she got three winners."

This problem ask me to first identify a random variable and describe
its distribution before doing any computations. I'm having trouble determine which kind of distribution should I use for it. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well you need the probability that she selected 3 tickets out of 6 and 7 out of 27. In total you need to have 6 out of 30. The distribution for such problems is called Negative Binomial.

Comment: Is this right, given that the outcomes of each trial aren't independent?

Comment: You never mentioned they are not independent. From the problem set-up it seems that the desired probability is $\frac{\binom{6}{3} \binom{27}{7}}{\binom{30}{10}}$

Comment: Can you explain with the formula: P(X=k)=((k-1)choose(r-1))*P^r*(1-p)^(k-r)?

Comment: @Alex I would agree with the formula in your comment. But that is not a negative binomial, correct?

Comment: @eigenchris I'm confused, is this question really negative binomial or not.

Comment: @eigenchris: my bad, it's hypergeometric.

Comment: @efsee Alex's comment gives the correct probability. We choose 10 out of 30 tickets (the denominator) and of these, we choose 3 of the 6 winning tickets, and 7 of the 27 losing tickets. To my knowledge this is not related to the negative binomial distribution. There may have just been a mix-up with distribution names.

Comment: @Alex Ah. There we go, then. :)

Comment: sorry about the confusion.